# ImageMagic big image slow resize

Tags: resize, imagemagick, ram

Hello i use imagemagic for image resize. I have big **jpg image 20 000px x 8000px** it's about 2.5mb i try resize to 95% with *convert and mogrify* like this:

```
convert -resize 95% source.jpg destination.jpg
mogrify -resize 95% image.jpg
```

I have free 6.5 GB RAM then i try to resize 50%. Thats resize very fast about 20 seconds, if i try resize to 95% i get result only after 9 minutes. What is most interesting then i try resize to 52% i get result only after 4 minutes **it's very big difference 20 seconds and 4 minutes but resize result difference only 2%**

What i seen in task manager then i start image resize process 50%. imagemagic process very fast grow up ram like this: `200 MB,400 MB,600 MB` and etc. it's about 200 mb/s. Then i resize 52%-99% ram grows very slow like this: 45MB, 47MB, 51MB and etc. only 2-3 mb/s. Then RAM exceeds about 1.3~ GB it's finish and get result. **I don't know why ram grow's so slow..**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with IM, but generally speaking, obviously 50% is easy to achieve : the simplest way is to take only every odd (or even) pixel. A slightly more elaborate solution is to do an average from a 2x2 pixels square (division by 2 or 4 is a simple, very fast bit-shift). And more advanced methods can be used... Still this is achieved very quickly, notwithstanding the large size of your image.

However 95% or 52% is trickier, because one final pixel somehow contains information from an unrounded (floating point... thus slower) number of original pixels (like 1.05... or 1.92... in your examples) which implies more complex computations (in order to try to produce a good-looking result), like bicubic resampling (apparently IM can decide to use different resizing methods depending on the source image, see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=17103)), hence this non-proportional impact on processing time.

Regarding the RAM it depends on the method used to resize.
For 50% the image is processed very quickly, so it's completely loaded in memory quickly also (20000px * 8000px * 3B/px -> 480MB + possibly alpha channel).
However other resampling methods will be slower, and may need more RAM for computations. What you observed suggests that apparently the image is loaded progressively in the RAM during the processing, not all at once.

Try playing with the `-scale` option, and take a look at the [filtering options](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/) for resizing.

Comment: I agree with you, but have a little interesting facts if i resize 50% or less like a 49,48,47,46,45 and etc. i get result very fast. But over 50% limit is 51%. With 51% get result fast, with 52% get result slow..

Comment: that's probably because it is first scaled to 50% and then again scaled to the final size. as 50% is quick and easy to achieve as FredP said final resize must process 4 times less data

Comment: @Rostok Quite possible, since it seems like a reasonable optimisation. But why also with 51% ? If I find enough time I might download the source and take a look.

Comment: @user3778390 what about your resourses. could you please provide `identify -list resource` and IM version. Is it Q8 or Q16?

Answer (score 0):

You could try scaling the image as it is read in, rather than afterwards like this:

```
time convert input.jpg[95%] output.jpg
```

rather than like this:

```
time convert input.jpg -resize 95% output.jpg
```

The former is about 15% faster on my iMac.